# Modify the .jsp argument in Struts

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to create an interceptor in Struts to modify the .jsp page name. The reason being that I want each page to be wrapped in a container page, which will include all of the defaults (css, scripts, etc). I have created a basic interceptor but can't see (a) how to get the .jsp page url (b) How to return a modified .jsp url.

```
<action name="MyAction" method="{1}" class="actionClass">
    <result name="dosomthing">mypage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In the above I want to create an interceptor that will take "mypage.jsp", and allow me to return a modified string - ie "container.jsp?content=myjsp.jsp". The actual modified string will vary depending on other parameters.

I have everything working - the interceptor is being called - but I don't know what to put in the intercept method!

Thanks

Comment: This is not the right way to apply the decorator pattern :/

Comment: Do you have a constructive answer?

Comment: You should take a look at Tiles3, or simply using <s:include/> in your JSP to include the same common header in all the pages.

Comment: I working within an application that was created a number of years ago so limited in the choices I have. I want to wrap each page in a container page, not include a common header. The container will vary depending on other parameters.

Comment: Define container: a page with the original jsp in an iframe, for example ?

Comment: You can take a parameter in the container and call an action that return JSP page, use control tags to check if a parameter is available.